Use a Date Found in a File Name to Update a Specific Date Content Control
I have a file that has a "mm-dd-yy" format in its file naming. Ultimately, I am looking to create a VBA that will take that date found in the file name, determine the weekday and its occurrence within the month (i.e., Third Thursday, Second Tuesday, Last Friday) and then update a date content control named "Next Meeting Date" with the corresponding weekday occurrence in the next month.
However I am not sure where to start. I was able to create a macro that will update the date content control with the name of the file but not sure how to draft the macro that will find the corresponding date. Can anyone assist?
The below macro is my attempt to make what I want. The only issue is that it isn't accounting for the fifth (i.e., last) occurrence of a weekday in a month should more than four (4) exist. Additionally, I question how if I organically want it to be the fourth occurrence in some instances or just the last occurrence. If I can only have one I would default to the last occurrence:
Sub UpdateNextMeetingDate()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim docName As String
    Dim fileDate As Date
    Dim dayOfWeek As String
    Dim occurrence As Integer
    Dim nextMonthDate As Date
    Dim formattedDate As String
    Dim datePattern As Object
    Dim matches As Object

    ' Get the document name without the full path
    docName = ActiveDocument.Name

    ' Use regular expressions to extract the mm-dd-yy date from the filename
    Set datePattern = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    datePattern.Pattern = "\b(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\b"
    datePattern.IgnoreCase = True
    datePattern.Global = False
    
    ' Check if the filename matches the pattern
    If datePattern.Test(docName) Then
        Set matches = datePattern.Execute(docName)
        ' Extract the matched date components
        With matches(0)
            ' Convert to a date using the mm-dd-yy format
            fileDate = DateSerial("20" & .SubMatches(2), .SubMatches(0), .SubMatches(1))
        End With
        
        ' Determine the day of the week and the occurrence within the month
        dayOfWeek = Format(fileDate, "dddd")
        occurrence = GetWeekdayOccurrence(fileDate)
        
        ' Find the same weekday and occurrence in the following month
        nextMonthDate = GetNthWeekdayInNextMonth(fileDate, Weekday(fileDate), occurrence)
        
        ' Format the final date string
        formattedDate = Format(nextMonthDate, "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy")
        
        ' Search for the content control titled "Next Meeting Date"
        For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
            If cc.Title = "Next Meeting Date" Then
                ' Set the new value for the content control
                cc.Range.Text = formattedDate
                Exit For  ' Exit after finding and updating the control
            End If
        Next cc
    Else
        MsgBox "No date found in the filename in mm-dd-yy format.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

' Helper function to determine the occurrence of the weekday within the month
Function GetWeekdayOccurrence(d As Date) As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    counter = 0
    For i = 1 To Day(d)
        If Weekday(DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), i)) = Weekday(d) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next i
    GetWeekdayOccurrence = counter
End Function

' Helper function to get the nth weekday of the following month
Function GetNthWeekdayInNextMonth(d As Date, targetWeekday As Integer, occurrence As Integer) As Date
    Dim targetDate As Date
    Dim currentOccurrence As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    currentOccurrence = 0
    
    ' Set targetDate to the 1st of the following month
    targetDate = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1)
    
    ' Loop through each day in the following month to find the target weekday and occurrence
    For i = 1 To 31
        On Error Resume Next  ' Handle cases where dates exceed the number of days in the month
        targetDate = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, i)
        If Weekday(targetDate) = targetWeekday Then
            currentOccurrence = currentOccurrence + 1
            If currentOccurrence = occurrence Then
                GetNthWeekdayInNextMonth = targetDate
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Function

